# Expression Engine 4 / Assets numeric value out of range for column 'filesize' error

Tags: assets, ee4-upgrade

We use Expression engine 4 and the latest Assets.  After adding a new external source (AWS S3), and trying to update index, I'm getting an error:

"Numeric value out of range value for column 'filesize' at row 43"

I'm guessing this is because we have giant files in our bucket?  Just looking for a way to get around this and be able to index our external source.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be an issue with the `int` range of the column:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284494/mysql-error-1264-out-of-range-value-for-column

It looks like you'll need to experiment with changing that column type to `VARCHAR`, or try making sure it is an unsigned `int` if it isn't already.

This could break stuff so test on a development server first. But I would suggest going right to EEHarbor support with this info as using that column as an `int` seems to be a bug in the software and they may need to provide an update that changes that column data type and makes sure the add-on code handles the changed data type correctly (probably casting a string that stores file size to an integer in PHP).

**Edit**

I just checked and that column is an unsigned integer type, so you have some big files going on. EEHarbor will need to do what I said to make the add-on compatible with customers who have really big files (from any source, not just AWS S3). Contact them.